# ImageToggleButton, can I check if "onCheckedChanged" was called by user or programmatically?

Tags: qt, qml, blackberry-10

I have`ImageToggleButton` in QML. 
and I use `onCheckedChanged` for checking when user change button state. Sometimes I need change the "Checked" state programmatically from QT, but I don't want `onCheckedChanged` is called in this case.
Unfortunately `ImageToggleButton` doesn't contain the method `onClicked`.

Is there any solution to check if `onCheckedChanged` was called by user or not? Or maybe some another solution.

I know that I can just use `ImageButton` and change the images from QT, but maybe there is a right way.

Comment: You can disconnect slot before changing chechinh state programmatically, and restore connection after.

Comment: Yes, what @DmitrySazonov proposes is seemingly the only way to achieve this. I would also recommend you to create RAII class for disconnecting slots temporarily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested by @Predelnik - RAII implementation.

```
struct Blocker( QObject *obj )
{
  QPointer< QObject > obj;
  bool wasBlocked;

  Blocker( QObject *_obj )
    : obj( _obj )
  {
    Q_ASSERT( obj );
    wasBlocked = obj->blockSignals( true );
  }
  ~Blocker()
  {
    if ( obj )
      obj->blockSignals( wasBlocked );
  }
};

{
  // ...usage
  Blocker block( imageButton ); // will unblock signals automatically
  // do work
}// auto unblock there
```